# updatePixels() not actually updating the pixels

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make a program that takes a string, converts it to base64, and then to binary. It then takes the binary and changes the pixels a black pixel for 0 and a white pixel for 1.

I've gotten the pixel array to change to what I want, but it's not actually changing when I call `updatePixels()`.

My goal is to then take the canvas and export it as an image.

My sketch:

```
let hw;
let input, button;
let binaryOut;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(140,140);
    input=createInput();
    pixelDensity(1);

    button = createButton("get image");
    button.mousePressed(txtTo64ToBin)

    loadPixels();
}

function txtTo64ToBin(){
    str = input.value();
    str = btoa(str);
    let output = '';
    str = str.split("")
    for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        let base = str[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) 
        while(base.length < 8){
            base = "0"+base;
        }
        output += base;
    }
    binaryOut = output;
    console.log(binaryOut)
    updateImage(binaryOut.split(''))
}

function updateImage(binArr){
    hw = factors(binArr.length);
    hw = hw[hw.length-1];
    console.log(hw);
    resizeCanvas(...hw,false)
    pixels = []
    for(let i=0; i<binArr.length; i++){
        pixels[i*4] = map(binArr[i],0,1,0,255);
        pixels[i*4+1] = map(binArr[i],0,1,0,255);
        pixels[i*4+2] = map(binArr[i],0,1,0,255);
        pixels[i*4+3] = 255;
    }
    console.log(pixels)
    updatePixels() //here is the updatePixels function call
}

function draw() {
    noLoop();

}

function factors(num) {

    var half = Math.floor(num / 2),
        arr = [],
        i, j;


    num % 2 === 0 ? (i = 2, j = 1) : (i = 3, j = 2);

    for (i; i <= half; i += j) {
        if(num % i === 0 && i <= num/i){
            arr.push([i,num/i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I'm very confused and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `updatePixels` function?

Comment: i'll edit the question

Comment: @chazsolo its been updated

Comment: @JohnColeman yep just realized that after poking in the API

Answer (score 2):

Please try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and isolate the problem in a smaller example.

Here is an example sketch that shows the same problem:

```
let button;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(140,140);

    button = createButton("test");
    button.mousePressed(updateImage);

    loadPixels();
}

function updateImage(){
    pixels = [];
    for(let i=0; i < width * height; i++){
        pixels[i*4] = 255;
        pixels[i*4+1] = 0;
        pixels[i*4+2] = 0;
        pixels[i*4+3] = 255;
    }
    updatePixels();
}

function draw() {
    noLoop();
}
```

We might expect this to turn the canvas red when we click the button, but it does not. See how this example is easier to play with, because we don't have to think about any of your logic?

Anyway, the problem is caused by this line:

```
 pixels = [];
```

Take that line out, and the example program works.

My guess is this is because `pixels` is **not** a standard JavaScript array. From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels):

> [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) containing the values for all the pixels in the display window.
>
> ...
>
> Note that this is not a standard javascript array.

Comment: The pixel array is way too large which is why I cleared it out or thought I had. Is there a better way to empty it so I can fill it?

Comment: @MatthewMorrissette Why do you think you need to empty it out before you fill it? Are you getting an error?

Comment: The pixel array is supposed to have 4 indexes per pixel one for each rgba. If I put in hello world, I'm expecting an 8 by 16 image which is 128 pixels and 512 indexes. How it shows up now is a line across the top

Comment: @MatthewMorrissette I would take a closer look at your logic then. I don't think the size of the array is the cause of the problem. Try to step through your code with a debugger, or add print statements to get a better idea of what's going on. If you still can't figure it out, please ask a new question in a new post, and include an updated [mcve] that focuses on just the part of the code that's behaving differently from what you expected. Good luck!